# How to dynamically change the backColour of a richTextBox to control in visual studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to dynamically change the BackColor of a RichTextBox to **control** however I cannot find this colour in code view however I can locate it in designer mode using the properties panel.

I have used the following code to change BackColour to red, but cant use the same method for accessing the control color;

```
tbx_description.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Does anyone know how I can use the **control** color as a BackColor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [SystemColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class to access special colours.

```
tbx_description.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
```